# Write coordinates to new shp file columns with OGR

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, pyqgis, ogr

I'm trying to get the location coordinates written to a shp file after reprojecting it.  I have shp files that are in WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) and I reproject them into UTM 13N (EPSG:27700).  I then want to add two columns and populate them with the UTM coordinates, the new projection.  I know that this is easy to do with QGIS in the attribute table but I have several files and would like to find a way to batch the process and handle several files at once so I am hoping there is an OGR method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following script and loop through every shapefile you need to reproject. Alternatively, `ogr` will treat a folder full of shapefiles as a data set (`ds`) and each shapefile as a layer (`lyr`), so you could simply declare `ds` as the folder where all your shapefiles are and loop through the layers (shapefiles).

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr

# Create the UTM Spatial Reference
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(27700)

# Read existing shapefile
fn = "shapefile"
ds = ogr.Open(fn)
lyr = ds.GetLayer()

# Create new shapefile
new_fn = "new_shapefile"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
new_ds = driver.CreateDataSource(new_fn)
new_lyr = new_ds.CreateLayer('UTM', sr, ogr.wkbPoint)

# Copy the original attrbiute fields
new_lyr.CreteFields(lyr.schema)

# Create the two UTM attribute fields
coord_fld = ogr.FieldDefn('UTM_x', ogr.OFTReal)
coord_fld.SetWidth(8)
coord_fld.SetPrecision(3)
new_lyr.CreateField(coord_fld)
coord_fld.SetName('UTM_y')
new_lyr.CreateField(coord_fld)

# Create dummy feature (to re-use) for the new shapefile
new_feat = ogr.Feature(new_lyr.GetLayerDefn())

# Loop through the features in the original shapefile
for feat in lyr:

    # Get input geometry
    geom = feat.geometry().Clone()

    # Transform and set new geometry
    geom.TransformTo(sr)
    new_feat.SetGeometry(geom)

    # Populate original attribute fields
    for i in range(feat.GetFieldCount()):
        value = feat.GetField(i)
        new_feat.SetField(i, value)

    # Populate UTM attribute fields
    new_feat.SetField('UTM_x', geom.GetX())
    new_feat.SetField('UTM_y', geom.GetY())

    # Create actual new feature
    new_lyr.CreateFeature(new_feat)

del ds, new_ds
```

Comment: @Marcello Villa Thanks for the direction.  However, I can't get this to work.  I made fn the path to a .shp file

Comment: @Casivio Could you elaborate why it is not working?

Comment: @Marcello Villa I was and accidentally pressed enter so it posted. 

I set fn = 'path to a .shp file' and new_fn = 'path with a new name'. This produces the error: new_lyr.CreateField(coord_fld)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateField'.  

I also tried setting ds = ogr.Open('path to folder with .shp files) and it produced this error: lyr = ds.GetLayer()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayer' 

I tried ds = 'path to folder' which did not work because it was a string.  I am using Pythong 2.7 in case that makes a difference

Comment: @Casivio It looks like `ogr` is not being able to open the shapefile nor create the new one. Are yopu sure the paths are correct? Could you paste them here?

Comment: @Marcello Villa I do not think that is the case.  I'm using fn = path+os.sep+'Data'+os.sep+'shp Location Files'+os.sep+'ESRI Shapefile'+os.sep+'WGS_84'+os.sep+'UTM_13N_Americium-241.shp' which prints out as 'C:\\Projects\\770- LANL\\SLVs\\Data\\shp Location Files\\ESRI Shapefile\\WGS_84\\UTM_13N_Americium-241.shp' when called.

Comment: @Casivio Try to avoid spaces in the path and see if it works.

Comment: @Marcello Villa This still does not work.  Now I get an error at new_lyr.CreateField(coord_fld) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateField'. When I call new_lyr, it returns nothing.  Is the assignment correct?  new_lyr = ds.CreateLayer('UTM', sr, ogr.wkbPoint)

Comment: My fault, it should be `new_lyr=new_ds.CreateLayer('UTM', sr, ogr.wkbPoint)`. Furthermore, I looked up the UTM Zone 13N and its EPSG is 32613 and not 27700. http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-13n/

Comment: @Marcello Villa That got me a littler further.  It did create a new .shp file but it does not seem to be functional.  It produced this error: new_feat.SetGeometry()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogr.py", line 2146, in SetGeometry
    return _ogr.Feature_SetGeometry(self, *args)
TypeError: Feature_SetGeometry expected 2 arguments, got 1

Comment: @Casivio Sorry, my fault again. Forgot to pass `geom` as an argument. Should be like this: `new_feat.SetGeometry(geom)`

Comment: @ Marcello Villa  Great! Now it works but my newly created .shp file has only the new columns. Is there something that I can do to write all of the existing data to the new files?

Comment: @Casivio I just edited the code. Test it and let me know if it works.

Comment: @Marcello Villa  Everything is good now.  Thanks so much!